# How to use PHP variables in Soap requests?

Tags: php, soap

I am using a soap element in my code, and now I am facing a problem.
I want to add a PHP variable in the soap element:

```
<HotelRef HotelCode="00001659"/>
```

Here instead of 00001659, I have to use dynamic PHP variable like below:

```
$hotel_id
```

I have tried directly by putting the variable in place of HotelCode, but it is not working.

How can I do this? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share how you are putting.

Comment: @Suresh Kamrushi..<HotelRef HotelCode="$hotel_id"/>

Comment: can you share complete code? I think you are messing up with single and double quote only.

Comment: @Suresh Kamrushi...Thank you..It was issues with the quotes only..

Answer (score 0):

`<HotelRef HotelCode="<?php echo $hotel_id ?>"/>`